# Allocate status 4205

Tags: fortran

When I allocate an array, the stat is 4205.

```
REAL, ALLOCATE :: globbuf(:)
ALLOCATE(globbuf(allocSize, stat=test)
```

the value of `test` is 4205. What is the problem of the stat?

Comment: Any non-zero value from `stat=` has a meaning which depends entirely on the compiler used.  You'll need to specify details.  But then, if you don't use `stat=` you'll probably get a helpful message on abort (or you could use `errmsg=`).

Comment: The code fragment has at least two errors in it.  Please ensure you ask with compilable code.